# Heaptrack not detecting memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, perf

During my analysis of the memory leak in the below code with `valgrid` and `heaptrack`, I discovered that `heaptrack` does not detect the leak in the code while `valgrid` does detect it of course.

The process is aborted with `heaptrack` and displayed as `'free(): invalid pointer'`. Valgrind doesn't have this problem.

It would be great if you could clarify if the `heaptrack` supports the C programming language? There may have been something that I missed.

**Here the code:**

```
void fun()
{
    char *ptr = strdup("Helloworld");

    printf("str=%s\n", ptr);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    fun();

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiled with:**  `cc heaptest.c -Wall -Wextra -g3`

**Heaptrack output:**

```
$ heaptrack ./a.out
heaptrack output will be written to "/home/.../heaptrack.a.out.3015.gz"
starting application, this might take some time...
str=Helloworld
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
heaptrack stats:
        allocations:            0
        leaked allocations:     0
        temporary allocations:  0
Heaptrack finished! Now run the following to investigate the data:

  heaptrack --analyze "/home/.../heaptrack.a.out.3015.gz"

$ heaptrack --analyze "/home/.../heaptrack.a.out.3015.gz"
reading file "/home/.../heaptrack.a.out.3015.gz" - please wait, this might take some time...
finished reading file, now analyzing data:

MOST CALLS TO ALLOCATION FUNCTIONS

PEAK MEMORY CONSUMERS

MOST TEMPORARY ALLOCATIONS

total runtime: 0.001000s.
bytes allocated in total (ignoring deallocations): 0B (0B/s)
calls to allocation functions: 0 (0/s)
temporary memory allocations: 0 (0/s)
peak heap memory consumption: 0B
peak RSS (including heaptrack overhead): 0B
total memory leaked: 0B
```

**Valgrind output:**

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
==3032== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3032== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3032== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3032== Command: ./a.out
==3032==
==3032== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
str=Helloworld
==3032==
==3032== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3032==     in use at exit: 11 bytes in 1 blocks
==3032==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 523 bytes allocated
==3032==
==3032== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3032==    definitely lost: 11 bytes in 1 blocks
==3032==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3032==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3032==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3032==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3032== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3032==
==3032== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3032== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Does heaptrack's "total memory leaked: `0B`" mean "eleven" (the memory allocated) or "0 bytes"?

Comment: As per the code, we are allocating 11bytes via `strdup` and exiting without free it. So, this will be a memory leak. Here, Valgrind reports 11 bytes lost, but Heaptrack not detected the lost bytes, so it printing '0B' allocations I think.

Comment: It could be relevant to allocate a different amount to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: You need to find out why heaptrack is crashing. Does it provide a core file to analyze?